# Dereferencing a pointer to an object for usage of an overloaded operator

Tags: pointers, object, operators

So, I have a class with an overloaded postfix ++ operator. I want to use that operator on a dynamically allocated object as seen below. However, I've only found 2 options for doing so and neither of them seem right at all. I feel like I'm missing some huge point of operator overloading or something. Is there a more correct/elegant/cleaner way of doing this? I know those are very opinionated words... I've been looking for a while, but my knowledge of c++ is rather limited compared to most of the people on these forums. Thanks!

```
Date * today = new Date();

today->operator++(); //option 1

(*today)++; //option 2
```

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, your two options are not equivalent.   Option 1 calls the prefix form of operator++(), and Option 2 calls the postfix form.   An equivalent option 2 would then be

```
++(*today);
```

Generally, assuming these operators of the Date class are implemented idiomatically, I would prefer this form because the postfix form introduces a temporary and the prefix form will not.

Which is more elegant or cleaner?  That is subjective.  Different people have different opinions.

However, your example employs a pointer and dynamic memory allocation (operator new).  That causes a memory leak unless the object is explicitly released using operator delete.    In many C++ guidelines, that is actively discouraged  (Comment:  this might be considered good technique in some other programming languages, but generally not with C++).

The approach I would use is to simply define an object of type Date, not a pointer.

```
Date today;    // look ma!   This is not a pointer.

++today; //option 2, but prefix form
```

By this simple change, there is no need to (explictly) dereference any pointer and, since there is only one operation, no need for additional braces to group things.   It also has the advantage that the object `today` will be released implicitly as it passes out of scope (e.g. when the function returns), so this technique does not introduce a memory leak.

This makes things simpler, which might be considered cleaner and more elegant.

Comment: Thanks for the response! Sorry,  I meant for those two statements to be equivalent.

Yes, declaring an object instead of a pointer to a dynamically allocated object would make the statement cleaner, but wouldn't that mean the class is then allocated to the stack? I don't think I'd ever want to do that

Comment: Then you get to use more cryptic syntax than you need to, by imposing a (largely) arbitrary and unnecessary restriction from the 1980s.  There are differences but the gains of avoiding the stack are rarely significant, and you give up a lot in C++ by insisting on dynamically allocating your objects to use the heap. If you must, use std::auto_ptr (before C++11) or std::unique_pointer (from C++11).  Same syntax to use the objects, but they will be automatically released - because the auto_ptr/unique_pointer is on the stack.

Comment: Thanks, you've been a huge help. I'd +1 if I had the rep. The reason I'm wanting to create my objects on the heap is because I'm planning on making a game at some point and want to avoid stack overflow. Tell me if that's still unnecessary if you don't mind. I feel like the only way to get from book learned c++ and real world c++ is just trial and error. I've read "Starting Out with C++: From Control Structures through Objects" (a Gaddis book) and I've been skimming through learncpp.com and picking up little things here and there. Any other suggestions? Thanks again, Rob.

Comment: Depends on what your game does, but usually unnecessary. If you keep a LOT of really large objects (measured with sizeof(object)) you might exhaust memory.  That's true for both stack and heap (heap limits are larger, is all).    The trick is to avoid creating (or copying) any object unless necessary.  Keep your code simple, get it right.  If testing shows a problem, then you can resort to the heap.  Use Standard C++ containers (std::vector, string, etc) as they'll probably manage collections of objects more efficiently than you can - but avoid creating more of them than you need to.